# Delete from table with no related data - WHERE NOT IN and JOIN both failing

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, where-clause, sql-delete

Consider the following table structure:

[image: Table structure with 3 tables]

I'm creating a stored procedure which will delete data from `RelatedA` and `RelatedB`. Afterwards I want to delete everything from `MasterData` that no longer has a relation in **both** `RelatedA` and `RelatedB`.

I tried 3 different queries to get the IDs for deletion

### Using simple `WHERE`

```
SELECT MD.ID
FROM MasterData MD
WHERE MD.ID NOT IN (SELECT MasterDataID FROM RelatedA)
  AND MD.ID NOT IN (SELECT MasterDataID FROM RelatedB)
```

### Using join + `IS NULL` in `WHERE`

```
SELECT MD.ID
FROM MasterData MD
  JOIN RelatedA RelA on RelA.MasterDataID = MD.ID
  JOIN RelatedB RelB on RelB.MasterDataID = MD.ID
WHERE RelA.MasterDataID IS NULL
  AND RelB.MasterDataID IS NULL
```

### Using join + `IS NULL` in `ON`

```
SELECT MD.ID
FROM MasterData MD
  JOIN RelatedA RelA on RelA.MasterDataID = MD.ID AND RelA.MasterDataID IS NULL
  JOIN RelatedB RelB on RelB.MasterDataID = MD.ID AND RelB.MasterDataID IS NULL
```

**None of these return any records** for deletion and I'm sure there are a couple cause I just inserted fresh records in `MasterData` (and there are no triggers that insert data in the related tables).

I actually have two questions:

1. **What am I doing wrong?**
2. What is the exact difference between my queries? (bonus)

Comment: Do the subqueries return data if you run them? (i.e. the `SELECT ...` bit)

Comment: @DavidG I meant that with my question, I'm currently testing just those. Updated my question to better reflect this.

Comment: Try to replicate this in SQL Fiddle, jsut for the `WHERE .. NOT IN` example. It should work.

Comment: Pretty sure the first one should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's look at the ones that don't work

```
DELETE FROM MasterData
WHERE ID IN (
    SELECT MD.ID
    FROM MasterData MD
      JOIN RelatedA RelA on RelA.MasterDataID = MD.ID
      JOIN RelatedB RelB on RelB.MasterDataID = MD.ID
    WHERE RelA.MasterDataID IS NULL
      AND RelB.MasterDataID IS NULL
)
```

The `WHERE` conditions will never be true because you're doing inner joins instead of left joins.

---

```
DELETE FROM MasterData
WHERE ID IN (
    SELECT MD.ID
    FROM MasterData MD
      JOIN RelatedA RelA on RelA.MasterDataID = MD.ID AND RelA.MasterDataID IS NULL
      JOIN RelatedB RelB on RelB.MasterDataID = MD.ID AND RelB.MasterDataID IS NULL
)
```

The join condition will never be true because `null` does not equal `null` (i.e `null` = `null` returns `null` instead of true) and the second part requires that `MasterDataID` be null.

---

```
DELETE FROM MasterData
WHERE ID IN (
    SELECT MD.ID
    FROM MasterData MD
    WHERE MD.ID NOT IN (SELECT MasterDataID FROM RelatedA)
      AND MD.ID NOT IN (SELECT MasterDataID FROM RelatedB)
)
```

This includes an unnecessary subquery but unless I'm missing something seems like it should work. You can rewrite w/o the subquery as (you can similarly also omit the subquery in the 1st 2 queries above)

```
DELETE FROM MasterData MD
    WHERE MD.ID NOT IN (SELECT MasterDataID FROM RelatedA)
      AND MD.ID NOT IN (SELECT MasterDataID FROM RelatedB)
```

Personally I prefer not exists

```
DELETE FROM MasterData MD
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM RelatedA WHERE MasterDataID = MD.ID)
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM RelatedB WHERE MasterDataID = MD.ID)
```

Comment: Can it be that my database is seriously F'ed up? I'm testing your second two queries with just one table now and when I use `where not in` I get no records, vs `where not exists` I get all records. What the hell is going on?

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester not sure, the `not in` and `not exists` queries should return the same data

Comment: Only `not exists` seems to work for now. I can't get it right using `not in`, and I'm doing exactly the same as you do. I wouldn't be surprised if this turns out to be an integrity problem with the database, it hasn't actually been maintained since it became in use which was years ago...

Comment: Not exists is generally faster for large subqueries so maybe not in is just taking a long time?

Comment: the weird thing is the query "executes successfully" in about 3 seconds while it should take several more (talking about hundres of thousands of records here). Might be some query optimizer "bug"?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using `NOT EXISTS`

```
select
      md.*
from MasterData md
where not exists (
    select 1 from RelatedA A where md.id = A.MasterDataID)
and not exists (
    select 1 from RelatedB B where md.id = B.MasterDataID)
;
```

Use these together (as shown above) or separately to assess the data. If satisfied it converts easily to a delete query.

<kbd>[See this SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/74033/3)</kbd>

Comment: We have a "No 'IN' or 'NOT IN' tsql in production code....rule.  I had a manager argue with me that "it doesn't matter".  I wrote a small test and proved that using exists and not exists was making a difference.  (I don't have the test anymore, it was proprietary code.)  I eventually left this company because this manager was trying to use his VB6 code skills to manage developers who had longed surpassed his developer skill sets.  Good times.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to do a `NOT IN` for the parent query. So start with this, it should give you all the records where there is no matching entry in BOTH related tables. This is what your first query does.

```
SELECT * 
FROM MasterData
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT MasterDataID FROM RelatedA)
AND ID NOT IN (SELECT MasterDataID FROM RelatedB)
```

Then change it to a DELETE:

```
DELETE MasterData
FROM MasterData
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT MasterDataID FROM RelatedA)
AND ID NOT IN (SELECT MasterDataID FROM RelatedB)
```

And testing with some actual values:

```
--Create tables
DECLARE @MasterData TABLE (ID BIGINT)
DECLARE @RelatedA TABLE (ID BIGINT, MasterDataID BIGINT)
DECLARE @RelatedB TABLE (ID BIGINT, MasterDataID BIGINT)

--Some test data
INSERT INTO @MasterData VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5)
INSERT INTO @RelatedA VALUES (1,1),(2,2)
INSERT INTO @RelatedB VALUES (1,3),(2,4)

SELECT * FROM @MasterData --5 rows

--Do the delete
DELETE @MasterData 
FROM @MasterData MD
WHERE MD.ID NOT IN (SELECT MasterDataID FROM @RelatedA)
AND MD.ID NOT IN (SELECT MasterDataID FROM @RelatedB)

SELECT * FROM @MasterData --4 rows
```

Answer (score 1):

First one should work. The second one is missing a "LEFT JOIN", it will not match non existing rows:

```
SELECT MD.ID
FROM MasterData MD
   LEFT JOIN RelatedA RelA on RelA.MasterDataID = MD.ID
   LEFT JOIN RelatedB RelB on RelB.MasterDataID = MD.ID
WHERE RelA.MasterDataID IS NULL
  AND RelB.MasterDataID IS NULL
```